# c++ program shows very different memory behaviour on different machines

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, c++11, libc

I have written a computer simulation in C++ that needs a lot of memory. It runs in iterations, and in each iteration allocates a large amount of memory that should be freed at the end of the iteration. It also uses c++11's implementation of `<thread>` to run stuff in parallel.

When I test the program on my desktop machine, it behaves fine: It never exceeds the memory I allow it and during time and iterations, nothing stacks up. When I submit the program to our computation cluster, however, the used memory (to which I have access only through the queuing software) grows with time and by far exceeds the memory used on my machine.

Let me first show you very roughly how the software is structured:

```
for thread in n_threads:
    vector<Object> container;
    for iteration in simulation:
        container.clear()
        container.resize(a_large_number)
        ... do stuff ...
```

Let's say, on my machine the container eats up `2GB` of memory. I can see both in `htop` and in `valgrind --tool=massif` that these `2GB` are never exceeded. Nothing piles up. On the cluster, however, I can see the memory grow and grow, until it becomes much more than the `2GB` (and the jobs are killed/the computation node freezes...). Note, that I limit the numbers of threads on both machines and can be sure that they are equal.

What I do know, is that the `libc` on the cluster is very old. To compile my program, I needed to compile a new version of `g++` and update the `libc` on the front node of the cluster. The software does run fine on the computation nodes (except for this memory issue), but the libc is much older there. Could this be an issue, especially together with threading, for memory allocation? How could I investigate that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on how old the GNU libc is, you might be missing some important memory allocation optimizations. Here are some things to try out (needless to say, risking performance penalties):

1. You can try tweaking the malloc/free behaviour through [`mallopt()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html#Malloc-Tunable-Parameters); use the `M_MMAP_MAX` and `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD` options to encourage more allocations to go through `mmap()`, this way the memory is guaranteed to be returned to the system after `free()`.
2. Try making your container's allocator be [`__gnu_cxx::malloc_allocator`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html), to ensure the `mallopt()` tweaks affect the container.
3. Try calling [`container.shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) after the resize, to make sure the vector is not withholding more memory than strictly needed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I tried the third option, but it didn't help. It seems as if there is some fundamental thing wrong in the interplay between my code and the cluster's libpthread (or libc in general). If I limit everything to a single thread, i.e., the main thread, it behaves fine on all machines. I gave up now, since the cluster OS is even too old to allow an easy compilation of a newer libc. Single threaded it is.